# How to mock or spy on primitive type functions

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

I want to test a simple function that calls `.replace` on a string like the one (simplified) here:

```
export const myFunction = (input) => input.replace(...)
```

Since replace is a built in [primitive javascript type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), we can't just spy on the `replace` function of the `input` string directly.  How can we spy or mock functions of primitive types?

Answer (score 0):

We have to use the prototype from the primitive's wrapper, such as `String` or `Number`

```
const replaceSpy = jest
  .spyOn(String.prototype, 'replace');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason you should spy on the `String.prototype.replace()` method.

The interface of the `input` argument is:

```
interface Input {
  replace(): string;
}

export const myFunction = (input: Input) => input.replace();
```

You can create a mock for this interface.

```js
const input = {
  replace: jest.fn()
};
myFunction(input);
expect(input.replace).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But, if the input is a string, you can just pass a string test data to the function. Because the interface of a string has `replace()` method.

`lib.es5.d.ts`:

```
interface String {
    replace(searchValue: string | RegExp, replaceValue: string): string;
    replace(searchValue: string | RegExp, replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string): string;
}
```

```js
const actual = myFunction('test data');
const expect = //...
expect(actual).toBe(expect);
```

Comment: I needed something to add a mock implementation to throw, in order to test the try/catch block in my function, and replace was the only place available.  Granted, you could say that replace never throws, but that's a different story.

Comment: @Alex What errors will the original implementation of the function throw? `input` is not a string? Or, you didn't post the complete implementations here?